# Riverpod, save result of future provider to use in other places in the app

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a api call class  like this

```
class GetSinglesApi{

  Future<List<SingleModel>?> getSinglesApi() async{


    String token = 'retrtert';
    final uri = Uri.https(getBaseUrl(), PEOPLE_TABLE_ID);

    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'accept': 'text/plain'
    });


    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    checkStatusCode(response.statusCode, data);

    try {

      SinglesResponse singlesResponse = SinglesResponse.fromJson(data);

      print("Singles response lengeth: ${singlesResponse.records?.length}");

      return singlesResponse.records;

    } catch (e) {
        print('ERROR RESADIN JSON: ${e}');
    };

    }

  }
```

I'm using riverpod with flutter to make this call, here are my providers

```
final getSinglesApiProvider = Provider.autoDispose<GetSinglesApi>(
    (ref) {
       return GetSinglesApi();
    }
);

final getSinglesResponseProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<SingleModel>?>((ref) async {
       return ref.watch(getSinglesApiProvider).getSinglesApi();
});
```

How can I save the result (a list of SingleModel) in a new provider so that it can be displayed other places in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the new provider and `ref.watch`:

```dart
final singleModelResponseProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<SingleModel>?>(
    (ref) => ref.watch(getSinglesResponseProvider).value);
```